# GUI for a GNU Debugger

Tags: c, memory-management, debugging, malloc

am pretty excited with the GNU Debugger and a GUI called **Insight** as it has saved me A LOT OF time. Thus I am posting this question/answer for other newbies out there like me having problems with their C code looking for a visual way to see what's going on.

I am working on Linux Mint (Ubuntu) btw.

Comment: And your question is? If you just want to share your excitement with the whole world, go for reddit or get a blog. SO is about questions and answers.

Comment: See also this question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/decent-gui-for-gdb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) especially if you have complex data structures to visualize.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [Insight](http://sourceware.org/insight/index.php) a GUI for [GNU Project Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)
2. Compile your source
3. Run the debugger

_

```
$ sudo apt-get install insight    
$ gcc -g source.c -o application
$ insight
```

[image: Insight]

Comment: Is insight still being worked on?  I thought RedHat dropped development.

Comment: There still seems to be project activity: http://sourceware.org/insight/news.php

Answer (score 1):

When developing for Windows using GCC. The best is to use [Affinic Debugger GUI(GDB)](http://www.affinic.com). it is newer design. it is similar and better than DDD. It also works for Linux and Mac

[image: Affinic Debugger Screenshot]

Comment: This is a direct link to some company's page...

Comment: @LuckyLuc he wrote it

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) has a nice front end for gdb.  So does [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org).

Answer (score 0):

Your are right that we load the executables, but when you are compiling you will need to compile with the debug flag (think is it -g in gcc, abit rusty on that ), that will insert the debugging information into the executable/obj files.

Answer (score 0):

When developing for Windows using GCC (e.g. MinGW), I often found it painful to get a GUI for GDB working (And I have a disliking for Eclipse), but I'm really fond of the [Code:Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE.